# Why i am getting waiting for support?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress.

when i run my website. it says wating for support.imagecd.net....

what does exactly it means that.

[image]

Please anybody explain me

Comment: It means that a resource is being loaded and your browser is waiting for it to finish, the resource is most likely from `support.imagecd.net`

Comment: i never mention support.imagecd.net in myc oode

Comment: There could be a million of reasons, a browser plugin, a add somewhere on your page. It has most likely nothing to do with your code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a malware. I had the same problem and I found a weird code including "support.imagecd.net" in my WP template's header.php file. Try finding it yourself, otherwise order a scan of your site with your hosting provider.